# Execute a class before test phase

Tags: java, maven, testng

I would like to execute a java class which consists a main method (this creates a testng.xml file) before my test phase starts (which consists of class with @Test methods).

Is it possible to execute this class before test phase using any command of maven? I want to run my tests using jenkins so I need to provide a goal which can perform this task.

Currently I use command "mvn test" to execute my tests.

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: There is a Goal `generate-test-sources` where you can add the function. it will be executed before the test phase

Comment: look at the linked answer, you can configure the `exec-maven-plugin` to run your Java main during a [phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) before the `test` one, as @Jens suggested

Comment: I've added the below in my pom.xml but I'm still not able to execute it:
`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
         <id>Maven executions</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>        <executable>com.test.CreateTestNGXML</executable>
      </configuration>  
   </plugin>`
which command should I execute to execute class 1st?

Comment: @SunilOjha you shouldn't execute in `test` phase but a phase **before** it, `generate-test-sources` would be fine as suggested above, also reading the linked documentation about phases would help :)

Comment: It worked. Thanks @A_Di-Matteo and Jens for helping.